Issue with Cart API Implementation - Products Not Being Added to Cart in Zoho Commerce
I am writing to report an issue I'm experiencing with the Cart API implementation. I have tried multiple approaches to add products to a customer's cart programmatically, but I'm encountering difficulties.
API Request Approach
I am making a POST request to https://commerce.zoho.com/storefront/api/v1/cart in Postman with the following configuration:
Headers
Cookie: 2-9e3fd03229afdb64895d0b07bce24969d3b7abbd417ae3d075cb4f68d5856f107200da65b0a26079343686901f2d60c0
domain-name: tiendasalud.synapsis.holdings
Request Body:
{
    "product_variant_id": "4509902000001524005",
    "quantity": 5
}

While the API returns a success message with the product details, the products are not actually being added to the cart when I check the cart page (/cart).
HTML Components Approach
I have also attempted to implement this using the HTML components and JavaScript in my Commerce headers code:
<script>
function LocalStorage_CartItems() {
    const cartDetails = "4509902000003924347/4&4509902000003924345/2"
    if (cartDetails) {
      const products = cartDetails.split("&");
      
      products.forEach((product) => {
        const [productId, quantity] = product.split("/");
        for (let i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
          addProductToCart(productId);
        }
      });
    }
}

function addProductToCart(productId) {
    const addToCartBtn = document.querySelector(
      `[data-zs-add-to-cart][data-zs-product-variant-id="${productId}"]`
    );
    
    if (addToCartBtn) {
      addToCartBtn.click();
    }
}
</script>

The format "4509902000003924347/4&4509902000003924345/2" represents:

The product ID (first set of numbers).
The quantity separated by a slash (/).
Multiple products separated by an ampersand (&).

But the problem is that the addToCartBtn returns null, so I think I'm trying to access to a component that doesn't exists in the /cart page.
I have tried doing an API Post Request and using Zoho Commerce Components
